# automatic conversion from string to myclass

Tags: c++, conversion-operator

I have defined a class

```
class Version
{
public:
        Version(std::string versionStr)
        {
            //do something
        }
}
```

I want to be able to use it as follow

```
void foo(Version v1) {//do somthing};
void main()
{
    foo("test");
}
```

I would like that v1 becomes an object as if I have done:

```
void main()
{
    Version v1("test");
    foo(v1);
}
```

is that possible?

Comment: What you have should work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: error: could not convert '(const char*)"test"' from 'const char*' to 'Version'

Comment: try `foo(std::string("test"));` or make a constructor `Version(const char*)`. basicly its telling you that `"test"` is not of type `std::string`.

Comment: @kam andre is right ... introducing a CTOR that takes const char* will do the trick.

Comment: Using `void main` is never a good idea. Use `int main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have has too many levels of implicit construction. `"string literal"` is of type `const char []` and **not** `std::string`. Only one level of implicit construction occurs automatically. Try adding a constructor that takes `const char *` instead:

```
class Version {
    // ...
    Version(const char *_vstr) : versionStr(_vstr) {}
    // ...
}
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/O3sQLG)

Comment: I heard that a overloaded converssio operator from string to Version can do the job. But I couldn't find that info anywhere.. am I mistaken on this concept?

Comment: @kam You are correct but `"test"` is not a `std::string` it's a `const char*`

Comment: @andre No, it's not a `const char *`, but a `const char [N + 1]` where `N` is the length of the string.

Comment: If you want to get really pedantic, `const char (&)[N + 1]`.